# Is Mint.com an adequate substitute for Microsoft Money? How does it compare?

Tags: software, microsoft-money, mint.com

I've been looking for alternatives to MSMoney since Microsoft announced they were discontinuing the product line, and came across Mint.com, which looks promising.

Are any of you using it?  Is it a decent substitute for MSMoney? Any major pluses-minuses I should know about?

Comment: What do you use Money for?  Which of the many features are ones you need to replace?

Comment: Mostly as a checkbook register, but also for tracking my investments and other financial data for personal income taxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to put money I am going to spend in my Quicken register (similar to Money in my limited experience) and that is the big ticket feature missing from mint.com.  Mint.com can only tell you what you did, or in a very general sense what you plan to do.

As a register, mint.com is flexible enough for me to categorize my transactions.  As a planning / budgeting tool mint.com is very simple and fast to get going, but lacks the depth of a budget I want to manage every week.  Mint.com also tracks my investments, but I freely admit my investment management is nothing more than putting money into the same accounts.  I bother with investment tracking other than looking to see it isn't zero.

I say try mint.com.  Mint.com has a place to totally delete your account.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that I recently saw someone post on twitter that Microsoft is making an unsupported "Sunset" edition of Money available.  If you're hooked on Money, you might want to investigate that.

Comment: Here's the link http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=60302e1e-207e-4710-ac80-d19c22e47488 It has all the online features removed, but it will be free forever...

Answer (score 1):

Mint has worked fairly well for tracking budgets and expenses, but I use [GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/) to plug in the holes. It offers MSFT$ like registers; the ability to track cash expenses, assets, and liabilities; and the option to track individual investment transactions. I also use GnuCash reports for my taxes since it gives a clearer picture of my finances than Mint does.

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade to Microsoft Money Plus Sunset for free.  Also try PocketSense, a free software package which adds online-services features to Money Plus Sunset.